# Swift Chart Error when changing the data source

Tags: swiftui, swift-data, swiftui-charts

I have a 2 view setup.

In my `ContentView` I have a filter button that has 2 options, `urgent` and `regular`.

In `DetailView` I am loading the data based on the filter from SwiftData. I passed the filter to the `init` and fetched the objects from SwiftData. When I load data for the `urgent`, for example, I have 2 items and switch to the `regular` filter, where the total number of items changes to something greater than it currently is, my chart works fine. But my chart crashes if I switch from the `regular` filter back to the `urgent` when the number of items decreases. The error is:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN

This is simple code to demonstrate the error. My app is more complex. The reason I'm using the viewModel is that I need to change the data I'm getting from SwiftData to show it in the chart. I mimic the functionality in this code.

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
final class Item {
    var isUrgent: Bool
    var name: String
    var amount: Double
    
    init(isUrgent: Bool, name: String, amount: Double) {
        self.isUrgent = isUrgent
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    }
}


enum Filter: String, CaseIterable {
    case urgent, regular
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @State var selectedFilter = Filter.regular
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Picker("", selection: $selectedFilter) {
                    ForEach(Filter.allCases, id: \.self) { filter in
                        Text(filter.rawValue)
                            .tag(filter)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)

                DetailView(isUrgent: selectedFilter == .urgent)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .animation(.default, value: selectedFilter)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(
                isUrgent: Bool.random(),
                name: "Some Item",
                amount: Double.random(in: 1.0...50.0)
            )
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData
import Charts


struct DetailView: View {
    
    @State var viewModel = DetailViewModel()
    var isUrgent: Bool
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    
    init(isUrgent: Bool) {
        self.isUrgent = isUrgent
        self._items = Query(filter: #Predicate { $0.isUrgent == isUrgent } )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart(viewModel.chartItems, id: \.self) { item in
                SectorMark(angle: .value("amount", item), innerRadius: .ratio(0.65), angularInset: 3.0)
            }
        }
        .task(id: isUrgent) {
            viewModel.setupData(items: items)
        }
    }
}

@Observable
final class DetailViewModel {
 
    var chartItems: [Double] = []
    
    func setupData(items: [Item]) {
        chartItems = items.map { $0.amount }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this but the posted code is incomplete and generates a lot of compilation errors so I had to make some guesses and make some shortcuts to make it work. Make sure you provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I found the issue, as I see, the problem is with the animation. I am animating the selectedFilter changes. if I comment out the line it doesn't crash anymore. Which is very strange...

Comment: I think this is some kind of synchronisation issue and then using or not using an animation could make a difference. If you still want an answer (if possible) to your question then you need to add enough code (selected filter, animation etc) so that it's reproducible otherwise I suggest you remove the question.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks for the reply, i have updated my question with the code. Not exactly my app code, but if you run it, it will replicate the crash.